# Integrate a product of an exponent and a product of multiple error-functions

Tags: integration, error-function

I'm trying to evaluate the following integral:

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2} \left[ \text{erf } \left(a x + b\right) \right]^{k} dx.$$

And I found a formula for a similar integral in [this](https://intra.ece.ucr.edu/%7Ekorotkov/papers/Korotkov-book-integrals.pdf) book (formulas 3, 4 in section 2.3.3. (p. 55)), however it's not exactly what I'm looking for.

Is there a closed-form expression for that integral?
I would appreciate any suggestions and/or hints.

To give some more background, I started from this integral:
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \phi(x) \left[ \Phi \left(c x + d\right) \right]^{k} dx$$
where $\phi(\cdot), \Phi(\cdot)$ are the PDF and CDF of the standard normal distribution. I developed it to a sum of integrals, based on the relation between $\Phi(x)$ and $\text{erf}(x)$, where each one of the integrals in the sum is of the form of the integral above.

Comment: What is $\operatorname{erf}^{\,k}$? Is it $k$ applications of $\operatorname{erf}$? Or the $k$th power of a single application of $\operatorname{erf}$? Or something else entirely?

Comment: @BrianTung I edited the question to make it clearer. It's a product of $k$ error-functions

Comment: Where is $i$ in the first equation ? Is it $a_i$ and $b_i$ ?

Comment: No, it's a product of the CDF/error-function with the same argument. I edited to make it clearer